# Remove JSON Field In MySQL [PHP] [CodeIgniter]

Tags: php, mysql, json

I wrote a function to accept a 'product_id' and then it will cycle through all my Json fields to find all the json objects without the id 'product id' and then I need it encode it back and update database.

currently I substituted 'product_id' with '154' since that is a 'id' I am testing to remove.

This Foreach statement I wrote gets me all the ids

```
$user = $this->session->userdata('user_id');

    $autoOrder = $this->db->get_where('auto_order', ['user_id' => $user])->row()->products;

    $temp = json_decode($autoOrder);


    foreach ($temp as  $value) {
       $last_value = (array)$value;
       foreach ($last_value as  $key=> $value) {
         foreach($value as $key2=>$value2) {
           if ($key2 == 'id' && $value2 != '154') {
             echo "Product Id: " . $value2 . "<br>";
             $new_ids[] = $value2;
           }
        }
     }
    }
```

How can I now cycle through all the autoOrder and retrieve only the ones with 'new_ids'?

Example How The JSON Looks:

```
[
    {
        "order": {
            "id": "154",
            "qty": "1",
            "option": "{\"color\":{\"title\":\"Color\",\"value\":null}}",
            "price": "2433.62",
            "name": "Race Car",
            "shipping": "0",
            "tax": "26",
            "image": "http://localhost/products/image/34",
            "coupon": ""
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Its a table in the db

Comment: Remove a JSON field with the supplied product id

Comment: ////////////Yes

Answer (score 0):

This code you wrote it's a bit complicated to understand. 
Anyway, you should save the new_ids into the DataBase, and then execute the query specifying the condition to retrieve only the object without new_ids on the WHERE.